# How to update big table from csv file/another table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, csv

we have a table of about 3M records that's intensively used in our apps for read only operations. Once a day we receive a csv file with a new version of the table. Most of the records are not changed, however some are created, updated or deleted. The total amount of changes is less than 1% of the whole content.
What would be the best way of updating the table content with the new data? The table exclusive lock is not acceptable, the app is working 24/7.
The update should be done in one commit. The access to the DB is via JDBC.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at loading your data into a global temporary table, then using a MERGE statement to join between that and the target table on a common and unique key value, and thus apply the changes.

There are plenty of MERGE examples on SO, and in the documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: Does MERGE delete records?

Comment: It looks like MERGE is not capable of deleting records from the target table that are not presented in the source table.

Comment: Ok, actually, MERGE followed by DELETE is doing what's required.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to maintain a pair of tables and switch the application between them by using a synonym.

So given table1 and table2, your synonym points to table1 on Monday. Overnight you load up table2, then switch the synonym to point to it instead of table1.

An indirect advantage of this is that it preserves your previous data set in case you need to switch back to it.

Comment: It's been a while since I did it, but as I recall there was no locking issue on the synonym definition because once a query was running you could do what you like with the synonym because the underlying relation was resolved as part of the query parsing and transformation. It would be quite simple to test.